# MVC 5: Multiple authentication schemes for a single web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs

My MVC5 application maintains its own user credentials and now I want to authenticate partner users using ADFS. My question is that does MVC5 support multiple authentication schemes in a single application? If yes, how could I achieve it?

Comment: Where are the user credentials stored? SQL DB?

Comment: Yes. It's stored in SQL

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to use [Identity Server 3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/) and federate with ADFS.

The user can then pick which STS to authenticate on i.e. SQL or AD.